# comparison of Fixnum with nil failed even after changing to integer

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I am learning Ruby and insert sort algorithms.

The following code gives an error with `comparison of Fixnum with nil failed` and I am not sure why.

I appreciate any inputs.

```
def insert_sort(arr)
  arr = arr.map(&:to_i) # change string in array to integer
  [*1..arr.length].each do |j|
    key = arr[j]
    i = j - 1
    while i >= 0 and arr[i] > key # error in this line
      arr[i + 1] = arr[i]
      i = i - 1
    end
    arr[i + 1] = key
  end
end
```

Error details:

```
Failure/Error: insert_sort([5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3]).should == [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 ArgumentError:
   comparison of Fixnum with nil failed
 # ./lib/insert_sort.rb:6:in `>'
 # ./lib/insert_sort.rb:6:in `block in insert_sort'
 # ./lib/insert_sort.rb:3:in `each'
 # ./lib/insert_sort.rb:3:in `insert_sort'
 # ./spec/lib/insert_sort_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The original pseudocode:

```
1 for j = 2 to A.length
2 key = A[j]
3 // Insert A[j] into the sorted sequence A[1..j-1].
4 i=j-1
5 while i>0 and A[i] > key
6 A[i+1] = A[i]
7 i = i - 1
8 A[i+1]=key
```

Comment: shin, when describing a problem in which an exception was raised, it's usually helpful to show precisely what the exception was and where it occurred.

Comment: @shin I gave you a proper answer. Is something wrong with it?

Comment: @shin, you should select the answer you found most helpful, if any were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To make you method works properly, it should be:

```
[*1..arr.length].each do |j|
  key = arr[j - 1]
```

Comment: It returns one less value. expected: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], got: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Well, that's algorithm problem. I'm looking for solution now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more Ruby-like way to write that. By using indices as little as possible you reduce the chances of having mistakes like the one you had.

```
def insert_sort(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |e,a|
    ei = e.to_i
    i = a.index { |f| ei < f } || a.size
    a.insert(i,ei)
  end
end

insert_sort(['7','3','1','5','2','8']) #=> [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
```

A few notes:

- There is no need to create a new array of integer-equivalents of the elements of `arr`, just convert them to integers when needed.
- By using [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to create an empty array, you avoid the need to add `a = []` at the beginning and the line `a` at the end of the method.
- You could instead write `arr[1..-1].each_with_object([arr.first]) do |e,a|`, but it's easier to just start with the array `a` being empty.
- If the element being inserted is greater than or equal to all the elements already in `a`, `a.index { |f| ei < f }` will return `nil`, so the expression becomes `i = a.size`, in which case [Array#insert](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-insert) will append the element to `a`.  Alternatively, you could write:

  ```
  i = a.index { |f| j < f } 
  i ? a.insert(i,j) : a << j
  ```